# How can I best structure a link/junction table with a lot of potential columns or repeated rows?

Tags: mysql

I'm making a site that will be a subscription based service that will provide users several courses based on whatever they signed up for. A single user can register in multiple courses.

Currently the db structure is as follows:

```
User
------
user_id | pwd | start | end



Courses
-------
course_id | description



User_course_subscription
------------------------
user_id | course_id | start | end 



course_chapters
---------------
course_id | title | description | chapter_id | url |
```

The concern is that with the user_course_subscription table I cannot (at least at the moment I don't know how) I can have one user with multiple course subscriptions (unless I enter the same user_id in multiple times with a different course_id each time). Alternatively I would add many columns in the format `calculus_1` `chem_1` etc., but that would give me a ton of columns as the list of courses grow.

I was wondering if having the user_id put in multiple times is the most optimal way to do this? Or is there another way to structure the table (or maybe I'd have to restructure all the tables)?

Comment: user_course_subscription as u have, with a primary key on user_id, course_id is the way to go. Of course you will have the same user_id (and same course_id) many times in this relationship table, that's its purpose ! But the tuple user_id /course_id will be unique.

Comment: Oh alright, so then from a performance perspective, this shouldn't cause any issues, if say, around 1k requests were made at any given moment to find the course subscription via user_id, and then load the chapters for their courses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your database schema looks fine. Don't worry, you're on the right track. As for the `User_course_subscription` table, both `user_id` and `course_id` form the primary key together. This is called a **joint primary key** and is basically fine.

Values are still unique because no user subscribes to the same course twice. Your business logic code should ensure this anyway. For the database part: You might want to look up in your database system's manual how to set joint primary keys up properly when creating the table (syntax might differ).

If you don't like this idea, you can also create a pseudo primary key, that is having:

```
user_course_subscription
------------------------
user_course_subscription_id | user_id | course_id | start | end
```

...where `user_course_subscription_id` is just an auto-incremented integer. This way, you can use `user_course_subscription_id` to identify records. This might make things easier in some places of your code, because you don't always have to use two values.

As for heaving `calculus_1`, `chem_1` etc. - don't do this. You might want to read up on **database normalization,** as mike pointed out. Especially 1NF through 3NF are very common in database design.

The only reason not to follow normal forms is performance, and then again, in most cases optimization is premature. If you're concerned, stress-test the prototype of your appliation under realistic (expected) conditions and measure response times to get some hard evidence.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer... I will look up joint primary keys and try to understand how they function together better. In each table then I guess my primary keys would be either the user_id or the course_id depending on the table

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's the meaning of the start and end columns in the user table. But you seem to have no redundancy.

You should check out the [**boyce-codd normal form**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boyce%E2%80%93Codd_normal_form) wikipedia article. There is a useful example.

Comment: start and end are subscription start and end dates. along with when the user registered/cancelled. I just didn't type out the whole thing. Thanks for the article - it's making sense now